# 1 ax, 3 graphs, 3 different y, all sharing x

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm having a hard time to get this done:
Need the two wiggly plots together and a bar plot upside down, on top of everything, aiming the wiggly ones.

What I have so far, without the inverted barplot:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(spd.index,sfd, color='black')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax1.set_ylabel('SFD', color='black')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
plt.plot(dbh.index,dbh, linewidth=1, color='mediumvioletred')      
ax2.set_ylabel('DBH (mm)', color='mediumvioletred')
matplotlib.ticker.AutoLocator
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b-%d'))
plt.margins(x=0)
```

One of the attempts, just made everything worse:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1,sharex=True)
axs[0].bar(r['rain'].index,r['rain']*-1)
axs[1].plot(dbh.index, dbh, 'mediumvioletred')
axs[2].plot(sfd.index, sfd,'black')
axs[2]=axs[1].twinx()

axs[0].set_ylabel('rainfall (mm)')
axs[1].set_ylabel('DBH (mm)')
axs[2].set_ylabel('SFD')
axs[0].grid(True)
axs[1].grid(True
```

DATA:
sfd:

```
datetime
2017-10-25 00:00:00    11.7724
2017-10-25 00:30:00    11.4399
2017-10-25 01:00:00    13.0397
2017-10-25 01:30:00    12.6578
2017-10-25 02:00:00    12.7908
```

dbh:

```
date
2017-10-25 00:00:00    204.472465
2017-10-25 00:30:00    204.475855
2017-10-25 01:00:00    204.484485
2017-10-25 01:30:00    204.490341
2017-10-25 02:00:00    204.490034
```

rain:

```
date
2017-10-25    1.2
2017-10-26    0.0
2017-10-27    0.0
2017-10-28    2.0
2017-10-29    NaN
```

This image is ALMOST what I wanted, except there's no upside-down barplot:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zIK8.jpg

I kept trying several ways and all I end up is with a big mess :( messy labels, graphics separated and I had to multiply the bar plot by -1: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPW6M.jpg

Please, help me!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have a toy data to play with? And also the expected output.

Comment: The expected out put are in form of the pictures, they are not showing?
I'll edit and try to add part of the data. 
Would be something like this !https://imgur.com/kIOgXG7 but with the inverted barplot in the secondary y axis.

Comment: @QuangHoang Info updated! Let me know if anything else is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
fig, (ax3,ax1) = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True)

ax1.plot(sfd.index,sfd, color='black')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b-%d'))
ax1.set_ylabel('SFD', color='black')
ax1.grid(True)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(dbh.index,dbh, linewidth=1, color='mediumvioletred')      
ax2.set_ylabel('DBH (mm)', color='mediumvioletred')

ax3.bar(rain.index,rain.values.flatten(), width=0.5)
ax3.invert_yaxis()
ax3.set_ylabel('rainfall (mm)')
ax3.grid(True)
```

[image]